# DistributedArrays Julia

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, julia, distributed

I'm trying to run this code in parallel by synchronizing the local Part of the DistributedArrays so that only the first line of the Arrays of the first process is 200 and not the first row of the second Array, can someone help, please?

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)
@everywhere using DistributedArrays
@everywhere using LinearAlgebra
n=10
Z=zeros(n,n)
#Z[1,:].=200
#Z[:,end].=200
Z=distribute(Z; dist=(2,1))
K=ones(n,1)
#K[1,:].=200
#K[end,:].=200
K=distribute(K; dist=(2,1))
#(i+1) % 2)+1,j

@sync @distributed for x in 1:nworkers()
localpart(Z)[1,:].=200
    @sync @distributed for i in 2:length(localindices(Z)[1])
        for j in 1:length(localindices(Z)[2])
            localpart(Z)[i,j]=10*log(myid())+localpart(K)[i]
        end
    end
    end
end
Z
```

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to do. Can you maybe show a working non-distributed version, and then try to parallelize it?

Comment: i already have it in a normal version, now Im trying to paralize the code over workers this is the normal version that works fine.

Comment: Have a look at [SharedArrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/distributed-computing/#man-shared-arrays), they are probably more suited to what you're trying to do

Comment: SharedArrays wil not wor because Im working on Raspberry Cluster

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if DistributedArrays.localpartindex(Z) == 1; localpart(Z)[1,:].=200;end
```

Moreover, you should not nest `@distributed` loop. Rather make it with one parameter eg. `xi` in such a way that the values of `x` and `i` are calculated on the base of `xi`